# Experiencing injection / brute force attacks

Tags: sql-injection, brute-force, web-hosting

I'm handling a hosting services for website via WHM. Few months ago, I've been experiencing some automated attacks on the websites that I'm handling. See screenshots below:

Are there any remedy for issue, for them to stop? This is the first time that I'm experiencing this, I now have [2801] permanent IP ban address in just a few days. I even edited my csf configuration, being insane that I permanently blocked IP address if they have wronged 1-2 times (from 10 as default). When I did that, I'm surprised that It's even more alot of IP blocks.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Edit csf.deny, the IP address deny file (Currently: 2801 permanent IP bans)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are already running modsecurity you can consider integrating it with a HIDS like OSSEC. It will automatically ban IP addresses that are detected as attempting injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I will research on this and will get back to you!